# the code is not getting compiled inTC. a dialog box with comment "Invalid breakpoint,, clear all break point " appears

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
int wh=1,i,j;
int sale[5][3];
clrscr();

for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
{
sale[i][j]=0;
}
}
printf("%d",wh);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Do not use Turbo C. Use a modern compiler.

Comment: why is there both `iostream.h` and `stdio.h` ?

Comment: @phoxis People love hybrid cars, why shouldn't they love hybrid code! ;)

Comment: @jonsca: i would like to add some shell script to, please add `#!/bin/bash` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you should ditch Turbo C, if that is what you are using - get Code::Blocks from http://forums.codeblocks.org.

Your error is:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
{
```

should be:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
```

Arrays in C are indexed starting from zero. So an array:

```
int a[5];
```

has 5 elements:

```
a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
```

Note it does NOT have an element a[5]. Any attempt to access a[5] (or a[6] etc.) leads to what the C Standard calls "undefined behaviour" - your program is in an unknown state, from which it can never recover, and could do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Code has errors. The array is `int sale[5][3];` . That means that the index ranges spans `0 to 4` in the first dimension and `0 to 2` in the second dimension. The index in C starts from `0`. so the loop should be:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
  {
    sale[i][j]=0;
  }
}
```

Otherwise in your code you are accessing some memory location which you should not (beyond the array.

Although this should not make the compiler stop you from generating the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Standards say using void main() is wrong. Some compilers will give errors if you try that.